# Chrome Extension access to unique client_id (UUID)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

Is there some sort of unique client id i can access with an extension and if not, can i permanently set some sort of UUID (like registry with IE or global prefs in FF)? I don't want to regenerate a UUID every time a user reinstalls my extension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that Chrome surfaces a unique machine id through a JavaScript API. Your best option would be to have users sign in using their [Google Account](http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/identify_user.html).